# minimize simulink library window

Tags: matlab, simulink

In my project, we use "add_block" command to add new blocks in a model, 
but it seems that simulink library must be opened first,
or add_block command will fail. To ensure add_block working,
we always use "simulink" command before "add_block" command,
so it becomes annoying that simulink library window showed again and again.

How can I hide or minimize the window? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of matlab/simulink are you using? I don't need to open Simulink to use `add_block` commands.

Comment: 2009b, is that matter?

Answer (score 1):

The library doesn't necessarily have to be opened first, but it must be loaded first. There is a slight difference in that you can load a library, using [`load_system`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/load_system.html), without opening it, i.e. it is invisible to the user but loaded in the background. I suggest you do just that.

Comment: I did as you said like below:  **load_system('newTest.mdl');**  **add_block('Simulink/Sinks/Scope','newTest/scope1');**  But it caused an error:??? There is no block named 'Simulink/Sinks/Scope'.  **open_system** also has this error.  If I do **simulink;** before **add_block**, it works. Then if the library window is closed, add_block also works, the error appeares if you have never open the library browser window.

Comment: You misunderstood what I said: it's not your model you need to load, but the libraries you want to use. For example, in your case you need to run `load_system('Simulink')`.